# Differences screenfetch vs. neofetch

Tags: desktop-environments, system-info

In a recently installed Ubuntu 22, I find slight differences between outputs.
I am only reporting here the meaningful differences: 1) Package count, 2) DE version.

```
$ neofetch 
Packages: 2685 (dpkg), 9 (snap)
DE: GNOME 42.2

$ screenfetch
Packages: 2693
DE: GNOME 41.7
```

What is the possible cause? (and which is correct?)

**EDIT**:
There are 3 numbers for the package count: 1. *NF-dpkg* = 2685, *NF-snap* = 9, *SF* = 2693.
As per answer by Artur Meinild and what I tried in a couple of systems,

1. `dpkg --get-selections | wc -l` gives *NF-dpkg*.
2. `dpkg --get-selections | grep "[[:space:]]install" | wc -l` may give a number lower than both *NF-dpkg* and *SF*.

Comment: Yes, `dpkg --get-selections | grep "[[:space:]]install" | wc -l` will always give a lower number, because this is only installed packages - not counting packages that has been installed but later removed (which IMO is irrelevant).

Comment: You can test my theory according to this formula: `SF = NF-dpkg + NF-snap - 1`. I believe this will be true on every system you try (it is for me).

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing a little here (since I don't have the time to dig through the source code of each application).

I found that the Neofetch package number matched this command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | wc -l
```

However, in my opinion this is wrong, because this lists both installed and uninstalled packages (which is not what I want).

So I created my own command to correctly list only packages that are still installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "[[:space:]]install" | wc -l
```

This gives me the correct number of installed packages only (which is significantly lower than the default number from Neofetch - which increases every time you install a new kernel, because older kernels are uninstalled, but still counted by Neofetch).

For the package numbers you see, here is the thing: Neofetch also reports number of snap packages wrong (by +1 because I believe they forgot to remove the header - can be verified by running `snap list`) - so the correct number of snap packages for you is 8 installed if I'm not mistaken.

Then I believe Screenfetch counts both `deb` and `snap` packages in the same line - so this matches if you have 8 installed snaps. But `deb` packages are still way off, because of the reason above - and because of this, in my opinion *neither number is correct* (if you're looking to count installed packages).

For the Gnome version numbers, the different scripts look up the version numbers in different ways:

- Screenfetch checks `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`
- Neofetch checks `gnome-shell --version`

The Neofetch reported version should be the "most" correct one (thanks Rinzwind).

It is verified that the [Ubuntu 22.04 DE is a "FrankenGnome"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AtyPdw5qNw&t=535s), mixing between version 41 and 42 components - which is presumably why it returns these different numbers.

Hope this still helps.

Comment: Please see my EDIT.
Useful answer.
Let us see if anyone posts a less guessed one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my guesses are well-educated - I'm fairly certain about the packages numbers, since I tested this myself.

Comment: screenfetch checks `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`. neofetch uses `gnome-shell --version`  and that should be the correct one (it matches the version in Settings - About). Someone with gnome could check these 2 as I do not ;-)

Comment: I'll add to my answer, thanks!